# How to use @route like symfony framework does

Tags: php, symfony, phpdoc

We do in symfony like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", defaults={"id" = 1})
 * @Route("/{id}")
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
}
```

I would like similar routing in a custom framework. How the doc can be pursed in code?

Comment: It's all open source. If you're looking at making a router for a custom application, just take a look at how they're doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Symfony` is using `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader` class to parse docblocks and search for annotations. So using it outside `Symfony` framework would be just using this class: read annotation and do whatever you like with custom annnotation.

Check [AnnotationReader](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/class-Doctrine.Common.Annotations.Reader.html) documentation and [this](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/12/symfony2-doctrine-common-creating-powerful-annotations/) blog entry with detailed instruction how to create your own annotation (this is `Symfony` related blog post but it's not using any of `Symfony` features apart from service container there )